# D7 form field #ajax callback not called on autocomplete field

Tags: ajax, forms

I have an entity reference field, and I'd like to do some ajax so that when a value is selected for that field, some text is displayed in a div below the field. Since it's on a node edit form, I'm using a form alter hook:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_blog_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_video_reference']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_video_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-path-div',
  );

  $form['my_path'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('My path'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="my-path-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 6,
  );

  if (!empty($form_state['node']->field_video_reference)) {
    $form['my_path']['#markup'] = 'Token path: http://www.mysite.org/node/' . $form_state['node']->field_video_reference['und'][0]['target_id'];
  }
}

function mymodule_video_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['my_path'];
}
```

The code works fine when a the form is displayed and the field already has a value.  However, the most likely use will be when the node is first being created, so I want this to trigger when a value is first added.  The problem is, my callback is not being triggered at all.  I'm following the first example in the "Javascript in Drupal" chapter in "Drupal 7 module Development," so from what I see, I it should be called when the field value is changed.  Does this not work for fields that are already using ajax to get a value in the first place (i.e. an autocomplete field like this one), or is there something else I'm  missing?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: In case it is an issue with doing this on an autocomplete field, I added another test field that is a select list and attached the ajax to it as above, but the form is still not rebuilt when I select a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `$form['field_video_reference']` is a container and you want to attach the ajax event to the actual text field element.

If you inspect the $form array you should see the correct place to put it. In needs to be at the same level as the `#type => 'textfield'` (or entity reference) property.

I think the path will be something like:

```
$form['field_video_reference'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_video_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-path-div',
);
```

Comment: Although I am not op, but i was looking for same thing from quite some time. I don't have words to thank you. It was helpful to me also. Thanks again.

Comment: @felix-eve, I owe you a beer (or whatever your drink of choice is). The actual value turned out to be `$form_state['values']['field_video_reference']['und'][0]['target_id']` (entity reference fields use target_id instead of value), and the ajax is firing now. However, I'm not getting the field value in my callback, but I'll open another issue for that.

Comment: Here's my [followup question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107737/value-from-ajaxified-form-field-not-passed-to-ajax-callback) for anyone interested.