# Value from ajaxified form field not passed to ajax callback

Tags: ajax, forms

This is a continuation of [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107354/d7-form-field-ajax-callback-not-called-on-autocomplete-field), where I couldn't get the ajax to fire on an entity reference field in a node edit form. With the following code, I'm able to get the ajax to fire.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_blog_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_video_reference']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_video_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-path-div',
  );

  $form['my_path'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('My path'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="my-path-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 6,
  );

  if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_video_reference']['und'][0]['target_id'])) {
    $form['my_path']['#markup'] = 'Token path: http://www.mysite.org/node/' . $form_state['node']->field_video_reference['und'][0]['target_id'];
  }
}

function mymodule_video_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['my_path'];
}
```

The problem is that the value from field_video_reference isn't being passed to the if statement in the form builder or my callback, so the value from that field isn't displayed in the my_path field when the value is first selected on the node create form (it works fine if the node has already been saved and there is a value in field_video_reference when I edit the node). I'm following examples from the "Drupal 7 Module Development" book as well as from the [Examples module](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/ajax_example/ajax_example.module#l287), so I can't see what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$form_state['values']['field_video_reference']['und'][0]['target_id']` looks wrong to me.

I would expect the value to be in `$form_state['values']['field_video_reference']`.

If you haven't already then install the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and then use can use `dpm($form_state);` to output the array to the message area and inspect it to find the correct path.

Sometimes for ajax requests [Devel Debug Log](https://drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) is also useful as it allows you to send a dump of a variable to a log so you can inspect it even if it is not possible to send content to the message area.

Comment: With Xebug and PHPStorm, I've used my debugger to inspect every available variable in just about every place possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with the code

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_video_reference']['und'][0]['target_id'])) {
    $form['my_path']['#markup'] = t('Token path: http://www.example.com/node/' . $form_state['node']->field_video_reference['und'][0]['target_id']);
  }
```

The issue was that you need to put every content of #markup into the t('text') function.